# Missing path after nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested-routes

A basic question about what happens when routes are nested. I have a form that's complaining about a missing path. I'm unable to figure out how to either name the path correctly in routes, or correctly change the path it's looking for.

Here the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :events do
      resources :event_sessions do
        resources :locations
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the form:

```
<%= form_for @event do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

The URL `http://localhost:3000/users/2/events/new` produces an exception:

```
undefined method `event_path`
```

What's happening here? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to provide the proper `form_for` parameter so that the form action knows how the resource is nested, for example:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @event] do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```